# Getting a 400 after setting json parameters

Tags: java, httpclient, json

I am trying to send the following json to a REST server from JAVA

```
{  

   "image_url":"image",
   "job_fqn":"jobfqn",
   "ignore_volumes":true
}
```

I am setting it as follows in my HttpClient

```
 JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("image_url","image");
    json.put("job_fqn","jobfqn");
    json.put("ignore_volumes", "true");
    StringEntity params = new StringEntity(json.toString());
    post.setEntity(params);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

This gives me a 400, after I remove

```
json.put("ignore_volumes", "true");
```

this is a valid input , not sure whats going on. The json from curl works fine, only fails in java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `json.put("ignore_volumes", true);`?

Placing the `Boolean` true instead of the `String` true.

Answer (score 0):

Try using true as a boolean and not as a string.

```
json.put("ignore_volumes", true);
```

Comment: perfect, that did it!